# How to get the unescaped length of XElement inner text?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xelement

I try to parse the following Java resources file - which is an XML.
I am parsing using C# and XDocument tools, so not a Java question here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
    <string name="problem">&#160;test&#160;</string>
    <string name="no_problem"> test </string>
  </resources>
```

The problem is that XDocument.Load(string path) method load this as an XDocument with 2 identical XElements.

I load the file.

```
string filePath = @"c:\res.xml"; // whatever
var xDocument = XDocument.Load(filePath);
```

When I parse the XDocument object, here is the problem.

```
foreach (var node in xDocument.Root.Nodes())
{
    if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        var xElement = node as XElement;
        if (xElement != null) // just to be sure
        {
            var elementText = xElement.Value;
            Console.WriteLine("Text = '{0}', Length = {1}", 
                elementText, elementText.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the following 2 lines :

```
"Text = ' test ', Length = 6" 
"Text = ' test ', Length = 6"
```

I want to get the following 2 lines :

```
"Text = ' test ', Length = 6"
"Text = '&#160;test&#160;', Length = 16"
```

Document encoding is UTF8, if this is relevant somehow.

Comment: how will you use it? Because you recieve 2 different strings. One is with regular space (32) and the other is non-breaking space (160)

Comment: Dmitry, I receive 2 identical strings! I want to receive 2 different strings !

Comment: duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512094/how-do-i-preserve-all-xml-formatting-with-xdocument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string filePath = @"c:\res.xml"; // whatever
var xDocument = XDocument.Load(filePath);
String one = (xDocument.Root.Nodes().ElementAt(0) as XElement).Value;//< test >
String two = (xDocument.Root.Nodes().ElementAt(1) as XElement).Value;//< test >
Console.WriteLine(one == two); //false  
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}", (int)one[0], (int)two[0]));//160 32
```

You have two different strings, and `&#160;` is there, but in unicode format.
One possible way to get things back is manually replace non-breaking space to `"&#160;"`

```
String result = one.Replace(((char) 160).ToString(), "&#160;");
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dmitry, following his suggestion, I have made a function to make stuff work for a list of unicode codes.

```
    private static readonly List<int> UnicodeCharCodesReplace = 
       new List<int>() { 160 }; // put integers here

    public static string UnicodeUnescape(this string input)
    {
        var chars = input.ToCharArray();

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var c in chars)
        {
            if (UnicodeCharCodesReplace.Contains(c))
            {
                // Append &#code; instead of character
                sb.Append("&#");
                sb.Append(((int) c).ToString());
                sb.Append(";");
            }
            else
            {
                // Append character itself
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```